# Is semaphore needed for read/write access to a boolean

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I understand the need to protect complex data structures. like linked lists, with semaphores. I've seen the bad things that can happen when one thread modifies the list while another thread is walking the list.

But is this needed for a very simple data field, like a boolean? Where I work, I see a lot of code like the example below, or get required to add this by code reviewers. Is this really needed? And if so, can someone explain what could go wrong if semaphores weren't used?

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
static int enabled;

int is_foo_enabled(void)
    {
    int ret;
    reserve_foo_semaphore();
    ret = enabled;
    release_foo_semaphore();
    return ret;
    }

void enable_foo(void)
    {
    reserve_foo_semaphore();
    enabled = TRUE;
    release_foo_semaphore();
    }

void disable_foo(void)
    {
    reserve_foo_semaphore();
    enabled = FALSE;
    release_foo_semaphore();
    }
```

Comment: `int` is not a boolean type. You can use `stdatomics.h` as a lightweight alternative.

Comment: It depends..................

Answer (score 1):

Atomic access guarantees multiple things (depending on the memory model semantics) -

- For larger data sizes (even POD) it guarantees the read or write are done atomically even if the value is split across different cache lines or even pages.
- For Read-Modify-Write types of operation, it guarantees that the read and write are done atomically, so no thread may read stale data while another is in the process of modifying the value. Another way of looking at that is that an atomic access guarantees the CPU will order all other reads/writes either before or after both read and write operations, but not between them.
- Additional guarantees may apply depending on your memory model (fencing, serializing, etc..)

You are correct about the first bullet not being applicable to boolean types (although that depends on your system, who knows how a boolean is implemented there..), but the other guarantees are still important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's needed, for example one of your threads can examine this value, and rely on it being `false`, then it starts do something like it was `false`, but right before that, some other thread changes it to be true, and that actions not needed any more, and even may lead to an error. Also, changing even a boolean value not really an atomic operation, or at least may not be atomic, so you it will lead to a big mess, when thow threads (or processes, if we talk about shared memory, for example), will change this value at the same time. So basicly you need to lock and release a mutex, when your code tries to examine or change any shared values, even booleans. Also in the context of your question, you have just an `int` even if it's used as boolean, i don't think anyone beleaves he doesn't need a mutext for changing integers.